# Best way to manage and serialize objects

Tags: c#, serialization, collections

I'm writing one C# application to improve my basic understanding of .NET, and I would like to know what is the best way to do what I need for.
Best means for me: simple to code and efficient to use.

My application have to work with objects (of the same type, eg. AAA), and it creates different collections of them... so I'll have a Collection of Collections of AAA.

My main needs are:
- to work with this main collection in memory and to persist (serialize) it on disk;
- to deserialize from disk into memory;

Another need can be:
- to "query" its data (eg. "give me all the collection in which contained objects has a specified value of a field").

Thank you for you indications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like xml serialization could be your best choice. It's very easy to implement, easy to store, easy to view, easy to edit and so in.

For example, you have a class AAA with some public properties defined:

```
public class AAA
{
   public Guid Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public int Value {get; set;}   
}
```

and a collection class:

```
public class AAACollection
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<AAA> Items { get; set; }
}
```

You **fill** your collection like this:

```
AAA a = new AAA ();
a.Id = Guid.NewGuid ();
a.Name = "test";
a.Value = 12;

AAACollection coll = new AAACollection ();
coll.Name = "First collection";
coll.Items = new List<AAA>(); 
coll.Items.Add (a);
```

**Serialization** to xml is simple:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer (typeof(AAACollection));
Stream s = File.OpenWrite(@"d:\test.xml");
xs.Serialize (s, coll);
s.Close ();
```

Xml will be like this:

```
<AAACollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Items>
        <AAA>
            <Id>b5d4f0ab-f34e-4a55-91db-f4737869f81b</Id>
            <Name>test</Name>
            <Value>12</Value>
        </AAA>
    </Items>
    <Name>First collection</Name>
</AAACollection>
```

**Deserialization** from xml is simple too:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer (typeof(AAACollection));
Stream s = File.OpenRead(@"d:\test.xml");
AAACollection coll = (AAACollection)xs.Deserialize (s);
s.Close ();
```

If you persist your objects with xml serialization, you can search for certain data without actually loading them into memory. For example, you can search through xml files or query  a database for records and deserialize only found items.

Of course XML serialization differs from binary serialization. For example, XML serialization serialize only public properties. Or you will have some difficulties with classes without parameterless constructor. XML serialization obviously has some niceties, but most of them are solvable. And despite that binary serialization does not have all these problems and it's way faster, it have its very own problems and generally it is not suited for long-term storing.

Links:

- [C# Tutorial - XML Serialization](http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization)
- [Basic Queries (LINQ to XML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943906.aspx)
- [Understanding XML in SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522493%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [Serialization Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6exf3h2k.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. By the way XMLSerialization created some problems to my code (infact class AAA is the tree-root of several tree-list of different type) and not serialize... I tried to mark also some fileld as XMLIgnore but not worked... Instead, in my case BinarySerialization works well.

Comment: What kind of issue it was? I mean, there are a lot of ways to customize serialization process. For example, instead of trying to serialize AAA object as is, you could create ToXml() and FromXml() methods with custom implementation.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, given the limited number of items, allowing you to hold them all in memory, binary serialization to a flat binary file would probably be a good solution. Check out `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter` and examples on its usage.

You could use a regular lists, ordered list or hashsets for the items in memory. If you do equality searches hashsets would be the way to go. If you use searches on the same **unique** field all the time, use an ordered list or alternatively a dictionary.

Also, unless you have extreme performance requirements, given the low number of items to be searched (a few hundred max according to your information), a simple linq query on a regular list will do the job fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I'm accepting the other answer just because it shows a full complete sample code and gives external references... but BinarySerialization is working fine on my example.